# appscript UrlFetchApp and slides export to txt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, urlfetch

I sincerely someone can help me with this.
My end goal is to be able to get the plain text representation of a google slides deck just like what you get when you are in the editor and go to File->Download-Plain text.
I need to get this txt inside my google appscript code as a string.

From what I have gathered so far this is not possible using the Slides API. Objects like Presentation, Slide etc don't appear to have export asString() methods. So I looked at the http requests executed when I use the UI in editor mode.

Turns out that if you replace the /edit in your URL with /export/txt of any google slide deck you get redirected to an export to txt.

So I coded this inside my appscript project with URL fetch to get to it:

```
var l_sDocID = _deck.getId();                            // A Drive File
var l_httpOptions = {"contentType" : "text/plain",
                     "method" : "get",
                     "followRedirects" : true,
                     "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
                     "Authorization" : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
var l_sExportURL = "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/" + l_sDocID + "/export/txt";
logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch(l_sExportURL, l_httpOptions).getContentText());
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong but  I get Error 400 each time. When I hit the same URL in my browser which is already authenticated to the google domain the redirect happens and I get the content I am after.

If there are other ways to do this instead of http round trip inside google I am happy to look at that but I haven't found one yet.

My project is based on the REST wrappers so uses DriveApp etc. I don't know if one can mix this with the V2 REST api without wrappers but if so I am happy to consider that also if it will address this issue.

Please help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to export a Google Slides as a text data using `UrlFetchApp` with Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- About the endpoint for exporting the text data, when you want to use the Files: export method in Drive API, please use `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + l_sDocID + "/export?mimeType=text/plain"` as `l_sExportURL`.

  - Also, you can use `"https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?id=" + l_sDocID + "&exportFormat=txt"` as the endpoint.
- In your request header, `headers` is not included. Please include `Authorization` in `headers`.
- `followRedirects` is `true` as the default.
- `method` is `get` as the default.
- In the get method, `contentType` is not required.
- `logger.log` is not correct. It's `Logger.log`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var l_sDocID = _deck.getId();  // This is the Google Slides ID.
var l_httpOptions = {
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
  headers: {Authorization : "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}
};
var l_sExportURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + l_sDocID + "/export?mimeType=text/plain";
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(l_sExportURL, l_httpOptions).getContentText();
Logger.log(res);
```

#### Note:

- If an error related to the scopes occurs and API, please enable Drive API at [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)

Comment: Thanks for that. Works like a charm. May I ask where did you find those URLs in terms of documentations? That has been the main issue in my code.

Comment: @s3frank Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About both endpoints, those are from [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) and [exportLinks](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), respectively.